# spark/scala drop row with nan in any column

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am using Zeppelin and `df` is the spark DataFrame. I try to filter NaNs that can occur in any row, however it doesn't filter it out for some reason.

```
val df = df_labeled("df_Germany")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [Kik: string, Lak: string ... 15 more fields]

df.count()
res66: Long = 455

df.na.drop().count
res66: Long = 455
```

How do I filter NaNs all at once?

Comment: `na.drop` should have worked. can we see the schema of your dataframe and also some sample data?

Answer (score 2):

> > How do I filter NaNs all at once?

generally following should work

```
df.na.drop
```

But there is *an alternative to use* `.isNaN` function *on each columns that can be NaN*. And we know that *NaN values can be possible in Floats and Doubles*, so we need to *get the column names that have DoubleType or FloatType as dataTypes* and do the `filter` as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val nan_columns = df.schema.filter(x => x.dataType == DoubleType || x.dataType == FloatType).map(_.name)
df.filter(!nan_columns.map(col(_).isNaN).reduce(_ or  _))
```

or you can use isnan inbuilt function as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val nan_columns = df.schema.filter(x => x.dataType == DoubleType || x.dataType == FloatType).map(_.name)
df.filter(!nan_columns.map(x => isnan(col(x))).reduce(_ or _))
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming df is your dataframe. If you want to drop all rows(in Any Column) which NaN values in any columns. You can use

```
df.na.drop
```

If you want to fill all the NaN values with some values, you can use

```scala
df.na.fill(your_value)
```

On multiple columns

```scala
val cols = Seq("col1","col2")
df.na.drop(cols)
```

But if you want to do this Column-wise, you can do

```scala
df.filter(!$"col_name".isNaN)
```

Or

```scala
df.filter(!isnan($"your_column"))
```

Comment: `df.na` not `df.nan`

Comment: Yes df.na, not df.nan, you can see the DataSet documentation here https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#na()